# How to copy JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Need to clone JSON inside the same JSON at different hierarchy level. Below is a JSON for example
Initial code goes like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "moduleName": {
            "content": {
                "moduleName": {
                    "property1": "Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text",
                    "property2": ['abc', 'xyz']
                }
            },
            "property3": "300438825",
            "property4": "item"
        }
    }
}
```

Result should be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "moduleName": {
            "content": {
                "moduleName": {
                    "property1": "Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text",
                    "property2": ['abc', 'xyz']
                }
            },
            "property1": "Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text",
            "property2": ['abc', 'xyz']
            "property3": "300438825",
            "property4": "item"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest an approach/Pseudocode  for the same?

Comment: need to copy property1 and property2 from content.moduleName to data.moduleName .

Comment: I think you want to make a copy and add two new properties to yout JSON

Comment: all the properties inside data.moduleName.content.moduleName to be copeid in data.moduleName

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But I think you want to copy data.

So just try this

```
function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
}

var arr = {
    "data": {
        "moduleName": {
            "content": {
                "moduleName": {
                    "property1": "Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text",
                    "property2": ['abc', 'xyz']
                }
            },
            "property3": "300438825",
            "property4": "item"
        }
    }
};


var b = {
    "property3": "300438825",
    "property4": "item"
};

console.log(extend(arr.data.moduleName, arr.data.moduleName.content.moduleName));
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hf02tx98/)

Comment: It should return the whole data again and i can't see the use of var b anywhere.